# Is it a good idea to train Neural Network for classification on dataset where each document has a different class i.e. no class is repeated again?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, data-mining, text-mining, recommender-system

My goal is to build a recommendation model for which I want to use Neural Network (LSTM). The user will give some input keywords and the model should return the suggestions (classes) based on relevance to the input keywords. My dataset contains few thousand documents and each document has exactly one class, so 1000 documents = 1000 classses. Every document contains 50-800 words.

My question is if it is a good idea to train a neural network on such data where there is only one instance of each class? If not then how can I achieve my goal.

I have already tried Naive Bayes and it works efficiently with such data. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to create some kind of **search by context** engine?

Comment: Yes more or less, but my ultimate goal is to return back top few suggestions (classes) based on input keywords by user.

Comment: So you are "classifying" the user input and not for example new documents? How many examples of user input with correct classification do you have?

Comment: I suppose you have a few examples of entries and what would be the best document for it. I've seen this applied to images using Deep Learning (see [Image retrieval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_retrieval) and [Deep learning for content-based image retrieval: A comprehensive study](https://ink.library.smu.edu.sg/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?referer=&httpsredir=1&article=3320&context=sis_research).

Comment: So you trying to create a Document Retrieval Algorithm by use of Machine Learning. Check these papers: [Legal Document Retrieval using Document Vector Embeddings and Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/abs/1805.10685), [CBDIR: Fast and effective content based document Information Retrieval system](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7166594) and [Interactive content-based Document Retrieval using fuzzy attributed relational graph matching](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7333896)

Comment: @NeilSlater Yes, exactly. Unfortunately, I don't have any test data so no user data. The input can be totally random but I am using keywords that are somewhere in the documents. Also, for testing my model since I don't have test set I am manually checking the similarity between model's predictions and user's input.

Comment: @PedroHenriqueMonforte thank you for your suggestions. Yes exactly, that is what I wanna achieve that but with neural networks. I will also definitely go through the papers/ links you have provided.